# How to read .text file (Data in Multiple lines) to excel row in Python/selenium

Tags: python, excel, selenium, automation

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')  # Add a sheet

f = open('202191391413.txt', 'r+')

data = f.readlines() # read all lines at once

for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].split()  

    for j in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(i, j, row[j])  # Write to cell i, j

book.save('pro' + '.xls')

f.close()
```

Getting error :

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated

Comment: `f.open('file.txt' , 'r+' , encoding="utf-8")` Try this

Comment: f = open('C:\Users\PY Scripts\Txttoexcel\202191391413..txt' , 'r+', encoding="utf-8")
            
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: try with just read `f.open('file.txt' , 'r' , encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: excel file created thanks, but i got those lines in one by one row. I need those multiple lines data (in text file) should come to excel in one row like A1,A2,A3,A4... example transpose (Vertical to Horizontal)

Comment: char \ has special meaning in text - even in path - and `\Uxxxx` means unicode - so it treads `\Users` as unicode. You have to use double \\ like `C:\\Users\\PY Scripts\\Txttoexcel\\202191391413..txt` or you have to use prefix `r` for `raw text`: `r"C:\Users\PY Scripts\Txttoexcel\202191391413..txt"`

Comment: Got output, looking for another step , please read  the above comment